# HowTo get all items clicks events in one handler?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

My listbox items are supposed to be links to TPanel. Info on TPanel will be different for every listbox item.

How to get all items clicks events in one handler?

Is there a way to get all event before they get into built-in OnListBoxItem1ClickEvent?

Comment: FMX or VCL? Smells like FMX.

Comment: FMX, I'd like to catch OnClick event handlers from every item from the list in one function...
- to do not create OnClick event handler for every item :)

Comment: please add firemonkey to the tags

Comment: Well, it sounds you want to create a common event method for all the items at design time. So then open the structure pane (SHIFT + ALT + F11), select all the list box items in that tree (by using shift key and left mouse button) and through the object inspector create an event handler as usually (as you did for a single item). That will bind the newly created event method to event you choose for all the selected items, so all the selected items will have one common event handler.

Comment: It's the solution but I need in run-time solution :) please help :)

Comment: What's stopping you assigning the same handler to multiple items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To assign a common method to the [`OnClick`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.Controls.TControl.OnClick) event for all items of a certain list box you may try to use the following (untested) code. It iterates all the items of the [`ListItems`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.ListBox.TCustomListBox.ListItems) collection of the list box and for each of its [`TListBoxItem`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.ListBox.TListBoxItem) item assigns an [`OnClick`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.Controls.TControl.OnClick) event method (which is assumed to be common):

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    ...
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure CommonItemClick(Sender: TObject);
  end;

implementation

procedure TForm1.CommonItemClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // this is the common OnClick event method
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to ListBox1.Count - 1 do
    ListBox1.ListItems[I].OnClick := CommonItemClick;
end;
```